# How Do I Set the Name and Value of an Editor Template Specific to the Model Being Edited?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to use an editor template to standardise the display of datepicker fields across multiple models in mvc4.

For example I'd like a standard display for the PublishDate property on a News model, and the EventDate property on an Event model.

I have created a Datepicker.cshtml template and set the UIHint to "Datepicker" for each of those model properties. So far so good.

But how do I set the Name and Value of the editor template to the current model?

**Desired Result**

I'd like to use the same editor template to create inputs like these:

```
<input name="EventDate" value="{CurrentEventDate}" class="datepicker"..... />
```

and

```
<input name="PublishDate" value="{CurrentPublishDate}" class="datepicker".... />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your Datepicker.cshtml template, and place it under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates:

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

And, in your main View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventDate)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tought of using :

> name="@Html.NameForModel()"

Same exists for id.